# Converting int32 -> hex -> string

Tags: c#

I'm reading an integer from the memory (`i` below). To convert it in to the character that I'm after I do the following:

```
int i = 99;
string hex = 99.ToString("X"); //"63"
string readable = hex.FromHex(); //"c"
```

---

```
public static string FromHex(this string hex)
{
    hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
    byte[] raw = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
    {
        raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
    }
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(raw);
}
```

But I suppose there is an easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert it straight to `char`:

```
char myChar = (char)99;
```

or use:

```
char myChar = Convert.ToChar(99);
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think this decodes using UTF8 encoding, but UTF16. Might not matter if you're only dealing with ordinary characters like `c`.

Comment: Well, this works for ordinary characters like `c`. Which I assume to be the case (since Johan hasn't mentioned more).

Comment: It should also work for other characters, e.g. you can try to replace `99` with `1337`. It will produce `Թ` character.

Comment: @TimS.: I believe the original approach is fundamentally broken anyway. It's unclear what the OP is *really* trying to achieve, but I suspect this may be it.

Comment: Yup, to clarify it's "a", "b", "c" and "d". So works perfect for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int i = 99;
var bits = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
Console.Write("Char: {0}", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bits));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, assuming UTF8 encoding:

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i).Where(x => x != 0).ToArray();
string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

But take note that the endianness of the machine(s) you run this on matters.